# How to reduce loading time required to display the output?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel-5, lazy-loading

I use this query to get a list of data from database and then display it using datatable. However, the query take longer time to load the data before converted to datatable. This application is built in laravel 5.

```
 $itemregistrations = DB::table('itemregistrations')
                     ->join('sections', 'itemregistrations.sectionid', '=', 'sections.sectionid')
                     ->join('categories', 'itemregistrations.categoryid', '=', 'categories.categoryid')
                     ->join('operasi', 'itemregistrations.operasiid', '=', 'operasi.operasiid')
                     ->select('itemregistrations.*', 'sections.sectionname', 'categories.categoryname', 'operasi.operasiname')
                     ->get();
```

The data ($itemregistrations) will be displayed in blade using foreach..

```
     @foreach($itemregistrations as $index => $value)                                               
              <tr>
                 <td>{{ $index+1 }}</td>
                 <td>{{ $value->sectionname }}</td>
                 <td>{{ $value->categoryname }}</td>
                 <td>{{ $value->operasiname }}</td>
                 <td>{{ $value->name }}</td>
                 <td>{{ $value->Nobadan }}</td
               </tr>
      @endforeach
```

Laravel debug shows 6 queries and 1129 gate results..

Queries list in debugbar

```
  select `permissions`.*, `model_has_permissions`.`model_id` as `pivot_model_id`, `model_has_permissions`.`permission_id` as `pivot_permission_id` from `permissions` inner join `model_has_permissions` on `permissions`.`id` = `model_has_permissions`.`permission_id` where `model_has_permissions`.`model_id` = 1 and `model_has_permissions`.`model_type` = 'App\User'

   select `roles`.*, `model_has_roles`.`model_id` as `pivot_model_id`, `model_has_roles`.`role_id` as `pivot_role_id` from `roles` inner join `model_has_roles` on `roles`.`id` = `model_has_roles`.`role_id` where `model_has_roles`.`model_id` = 1 and `model_has_roles`.`model_type` = 'App\User'

  select `itemregistrations`.`ItemRegistrationID`, `itemregistrations`.`name`, `itemregistrations`.`Nobadan`, `sections`.`sectionname`, `categories`.`categoryname`, `operasi`.`operasiname` from `itemregistrations` inner join `sections` on `itemregistrations`.`sectionid` = `sections`.`sectionid` inner join `categories` on `itemregistrations`.`categoryid` = `categories`.`categoryid` inner join `operasi` on `itemregistrations`.`operasiid` = `operasi`.`operasiid`
```

Sample Gate results in debugbar

```
  success
   array:4 [▼
   "ability" => "Edit Pegawai"
   "result" => true
   "user" => 1
   "arguments" => "[0 => Edit APR]"
  ]
```

What is the cause of the loading? Is it because query or foreach loop?

How to reduce loading time to display the output? Before this I use pagination and it works..However i cannot using paginate when using datatable as it doesn't search through all the queries when using paginate. It will only search on the first page of pagination.

Below is the result of EXPLAIN query in phpmyadmin of the above query

[image]

Comment: If it was me, I'd forget about all the non-sql stuff in the first instance, and instead focus on creating an efficient query, together with the indexes that could best support that

Comment: can you give simple example so that I have better understanding? Thanks

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

You can use With property in your Itemregistration model to load all relationships. Maybe add indexes in your tables can help

Comment: what need to be indexed? I have included explain query in the question

Comment: You have to index all columns used with join() : itemregistrations.sectionid, itemregistrations.categoryid ... and in others tables if they are not Primary

Comment: i am having problem to use relationship...I tried but not success